# Check if two rows in pandas DataFrame has same set of values regard & regardless of column order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe with same index but different column names. Number of columns are the same. I want to check, index by index, 1) whether they have same set of values regardless of column order, and 2) whether they have same set of values regarding column order.

```py
ind = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'old1': ['A','A','A'], 'old2': ['B','B','B'], 'old3': ['C','C','C']}, index=ind)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'new1': ['A','A','A'], 'new2': ['B','C','B'], 'new3': ['C','B','D']}, index=ind)
```

This is the output I need.

```
     OpX   OpY
-------------
aaa  True  True
bbb  False True
ccc  False False
```

Could anyone help me with OpX and OpY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tuple` and `set`: keep the order or tuple , and reorder with `set`

```
s1=df1.apply(tuple,1)==df2.apply(tuple,1)
s2=df1.apply(set,1)==df2.apply(set,1)
pd.concat([s1,s2],1)
Out[746]: 
         0      1
aaa   True   True
bbb  False   True
ccc  False  False
```

---

Since cs95 mentioned apply have problem here

```
s=np.equal(df1.values,df2.values).all(1)
t=np.equal(np.sort(df1.values,1),np.sort(df2.values,1)).all(1)
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([s,t]),index=df1.index)
Out[754]: 
         0      1
aaa   True   True
bbb  False   True
ccc  False  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that is performant and should scale. First, align the DataFrames on the index so you can compare them easily.

```
df3 = df2.set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1, inplace=False)
df4, df5 = df1.align(df3)
```

For req 1, simply call `DataFrame.equals` (or just use the `==` op):

```
u = (df4 == df5).all(axis=1)
u

aaa     True
bbb    False
ccc    False
dtype: bool
```

Req 2 is slightly more complex, sort them along the first axis, then compare.

```
v = pd.Series((np.sort(df4) == np.sort(df5)).all(axis=1), index=u.index)
v

aaa     True
bbb     True
ccc    False
dtype: bool
```

Concatenate the results,

```
pd.concat([u, v], axis=1, keys=['X', 'Y'])

         X      Y
aaa   True   True
bbb  False   True
ccc  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

For item 2):

```
(df1.values == df2.values).all(axis=1)
```

This checks element-wise equality of the dataframes, and gives `True` when all entries in a row are equal.

For item 1), sort the values along each row first:

```
import numpy as np
(np.sort(df1.values, axis=1) == np.sort(df2.values, axis=1)).all(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a new `DataFrame` and check the equality:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=ind)
df3['OpX'] = (df1.values == df2.values).all(1)
df3['OpY'] = (df1.apply(np.sort, axis=1).values == df2.apply(np.sort, axis=1).values).all(1)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
       OpX    OpY
aaa   True   True
bbb  False   True
ccc  False  False
```