# Comparing rows of a df accross 3 columns to find out if they all have the same string value and returning a booleen answer?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I test if the individual rows in my df are equal to each other across 3 columns?

```
if temp_df['Farm'] == temp_df['Zoo'] == temp_df["Forest"]:
    temp_df["The Same"] = True
else:
    temp_df["The Same"] = False
```

I tried the above code but got the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Field Farm Zoo Palace Forest The Same
T P D E C
T Z L E T
T P P E P 
T P C E L
T D D E D
```

Desired Output

```
Field Farm Zoo Palace Forest The Same
T P D E C  False
T Z L E T False
T P P E P True
T P C E L False
T D D E D True
```

Comment: df.equals could be your answer!
try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388062/check-if-two-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-has-same-set-of-values-regard-regardless

Comment: print out `temp_df['Farm'] == temp_df['Zoo']` for some insight

Answer (score 3):

```
df['The Same'] = df.nunique(axis=1) == 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Farm Zoo Forest  The Same
0    P   D      C     False
1    Z   L      T     False
2    P   P      P      True
3    P   C      L     False
4    D   D      D      True
```

---

EDIT: To evaluate only specific columns:

```
df['The Same'] = df[['Farm', 'Zoo', 'Forest']].nunique(axis=1) == 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Field Farm Zoo Palace Forest  The Same
0     T    P   D      E      C     False
1     T    Z   L      E      T     False
2     T    P   P      E      P      True
3     T    P   C      E      L     False
4     T    D   D      E      D      True
```

Comment: I like `axis=1` answers, but something to keep in mind with them is they are much less performant, so I try not to use `axis=1` solutions unless I know it's a small dataset or there isn't another solution.

Comment: I was about to disagree, but under the hood it does seem that `DataFrame.nunique` is simply wrapper of `Series.nunique` inside of `self.apply`. Thanks for sharing! DataFrame.nunique: `return self.apply(Series.nunique, axis=axis, dropna=dropna)`

Comment: @CameronRiddell for example if you 1)  tanspose the dataframe 2) do the calculation and 3) transpose it back (effectively making this `axis=0`), you would see a ~30% increase in performance (on this example): `df = df.T` and then
    `df = df.append(pd.Series([df[col].nunique() == 1 for col in df.columns]).rename('The Same')).T`

Comment: I do have a few other columns in the df how do I adapt this to select the columns I want to check?

Comment: @JPWilson you would first have to have logic on which columns to select. I would suggest updating your question. The questions is simple enough that you wouldn't have to create a new one, but it would be good for you to update input/output.

Comment: I have made the edit - as a side question how do you @ people on here?

Comment: Anrej in terms of performance which will be quicker your version or Stephans? The reason i ask is i noticed you spoke about performance. Although there arent many columns at the moment this could scale. However, there are lots of non connected dfs

Comment: @JPWilson You could increase the performance by transposing the dataframe( how  David Erickson wrote in his comment ). But if performance is not concern, I wouldn't bother about it - IMHO it's more important to have clean/understandable code. Also, only way to find out is measure it (do a timing with my version/Stephan's etc..)

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_df['The Same'] = np.where((temp_df['Farm'] == temp_df['Zoo']) & (temp_df['Farm'] == temp_df['Forest']), True, False)
print(temp_df)
```

would give:

```
  Farm Zoo Forest  The Same
0    P   D      C     False
1    Z   L      T     False
2    P   P      P      True
3    P   C      L     False
4    D   D      D      True
```

Comment: Stephan, I think your answer is good if there aren't a lot of columns. Also, it allows the op to specify specific column rather than the entire dataframe. Finally, the performance on this would be good, since it is `np.where()`:

Answer (score 1):

Since there was some discussion as to the performance of these approaches, I went ahead and timed some of them for future reference:

(note that each function starts with `if on_columns is None: on_columns = df.columns` to make these functions reusable, and all have the same/similar startup times. Regardless, this won't be the bottleneck that slows a given function down but for comparison purposes I made them all have this entry point.)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import math

# helper function: determins number of possible combinations without replacement
#  for a given array. 
#  (e.g. combinations of ["a", "b", "c"] == [("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("b", "c")])
#  This is a way to calculate that there are 3 combinations mathematically without
#  actually generating all combinations
def n_combinations(n, r):
    return int(math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(r) * math.factorial(n - r)))


def numpy_combinations(df, on_columns=None):
    if on_columns is None:
        on_columns = df.columns
        
    n = len(on_columns)
    n_combos = n_combinations(n, 2)
    
    # create boolean 2d array where all elements are False.
    # we will have the number of rows as number of possible
    #  combinations
    # We will have the same number of columns as the dataframe has rows
    # essentiall a given row of this matrix will represent the comparison
    #  of 2 columns in the original dataframe
    out = np.zeros(shape=(n_combos, len(df)), dtype=bool)
    
    # for each 2 item combination of items in `on_columns`
    #  compare the 2 columns, where the equal and dont equal eachother
    #  store this result in our `out` ndarray
    combos = itertools.combinations(on_columns, 2)
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(combos):
        out[i, :] = df[a] == df[b]
        
    # Compare across our output array to see if any values were
    #  all the same
    out = out.all(axis=0)
    
    # wrap in a Series to match output type of other functions
    return pd.Series(out)

def pandas_nunique(df, on_columns):
    if on_columns is None:
        on_columns = df.columns
        
    return df[on_columns].nunique(axis=1) == 1

def pandas_transposed_nunique(df, on_columns):
    if on_columns is None:
        on_columns = df.columns
        
    return df[on_columns].T.nunique(axis=0) == 1
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Field': ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'],
    'Farm': ['P', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'D'],
    'Zoo': ['D', 'L', 'P', 'C', 'D'],
    'Palace': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
    'Forest': ['C', 'T', 'P', 'L', 'D']
})

on_columns = ["Farm", "Zoo", "Forest"]
```

Ensure all solutions provide correct output:

```
print(numpy_combinations(df, on_columns))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print(pandas_nunique(df, on_columns))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print(pandas_transposed_nunique(df, on_columns))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

timeit results: (ran in jupyter notebook with %timeit)

```
%timeit numpy_combinations(df, on_columns)
1.18 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pandas_nunique(df, on_columns)
4.8 ms ± 901 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pandas_transposed_nunique(df, on_columns)
3.37 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Here we can see that the numpy approach is considerably faster than both `pd.unique(..., axis=...)` approaches. The pd.unique approaches arent really discernable from eachother imo.

Lets see what happens when we deal with longer data:

```
# repeat the dataframe 10000 times
longer_df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)
```

longer_df timeit results:

```
%timeit numpy_combinations(longer_df, on_columns)
32 ms ± 4.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pandas_nunique(longer_df, on_columns)
7.93 s ± 1.94 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pandas_transposed_nunique(longer_df, on_columns)
14 s ± 5.71 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Seems like the numpy approach is still the fastest! The pd.unique approaches were pretty slow, though ti does seem that `(axis=1)` is a little faster than transposing and working on `(axis=0)`

There's also the condition of making more comparisons (e.g. comparing 20 columns to eachother vs just 3) however setting up that data and ensuring there are some valid comparisons requires more effort than I want to put in. But that would be the next test because I would expect the numpy approach to lose some steam with more comparisons since it iterates over each combination of columns.